# Where does Mac OS X or Safari remember which application to use for Gopher sites?

Tags: safari

When I try to access a Gopher site in Safari it opens OmniWeb to open the site. Where does Mac OS X or Safari store which application to use for Gopher sites? (I assume Safari doesn't support Gopher itself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing Safari uses Launch Services, which means it uses the system's default handler for that URL. These settings are stored in the file `$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`. You can edit this using the `defaults` command in Terminal, or using a plain text editor if it is in the XML format.